# Download file OR send json result in single API call with axios and ASP.Net core 2.2?

Tags: asp.net-core, axios

Is it possible (or advisable) to have a single API endpoint that will return a json object with data OR download a file? I'm using axios and vue.js on the UI and Asp.Net Core 2.2 on the API. Details on why I want to do this:

I'm generating a file from the server on request. Happy path has these files being uploaded to SharePoint from the server, and the resulting document URL sent back to the client. The client will read this url and **get** it to download and **check out** the file. If the document could not be uploaded to SharePoint, I would still like to send the file to the client for direct download/save. I would rather not do this in two requests (get the results, then either download via the SharePoint URL, or request the document from the server) because I don't want to persist that document between requests. I am able to use axios to write the byte array to a file, I just don't know how to optionally read the response for the URL of the document, OR just write the byte stream as a file.

Answer (score 0):

For return different response types, you could try return `IActionResult` instead of the specific response type.

Try something like

```
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Upload(int id, IFormFile file)
    {
        if (id == 1)
        {
            return Ok("file path");
        }
        else
        {
            return File(file.OpenReadStream(), file.ContentType);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks @Tao-Zhou, that's part of the answer, but not the part I was having trouble with. My issue was more with how to read the byte array on the client and save it as a file, OR get the URL out of the response. I've figured it out and will post an answer later.